# How can I use @WebMvcTest for Unit Test POST method?

Tags: java, rest, post, junit, mockito

I'm running unit tests with Spring Boot and Mockito and I'm testing RESTful services. When I try to test the GET method it works successfully but when I try to test the POST method it fails. What should I do to resolve this problem? Thanks in advance!

This is the code for the REST Controller:

```
package com.dgs.restfultesting.controller;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import com.dgs.restfultesting.business.ItemBusinessService;
import com.dgs.restfultesting.model.Item;

@RestController
public class ItemController {

    @Autowired
    private ItemBusinessService businessService;

    @GetMapping("/all-items-from-database")
    public List<Item> retrieveAllItems() {
        return businessService.retrieveAllItems(); 
    }

    @PostMapping("/items")
    public Item addItem(@RequestBody Item item) {
        Item savedItem = businessService.addAnItem(item); 

        return savedItem;
    }
}
```

Business Layer:

```
package com.dgs.restfultesting.business;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.dgs.restfultesting.data.ItemRepository;
import com.dgs.restfultesting.model.Item;

@Component
public class ItemBusinessService {

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository repository;

    public Item retrieveHardcodedItem() {
        return new Item(1, "Book", 10, 100); 
    }

    public List<Item> retrieveAllItems() {

        List<Item> items = repository.findAll(); 

        for (Item item : items) {
            item.setValue(item.getPrice() * item.getQuantity());  
        }

        return items;  
    }

    public Item addAnItem(Item item) {
        return repository.save(item); 
    }
}
```

ItemControllerTest:

```
package com.dgs.restfultesting.controller;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.header;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;

import com.dgs.restfultesting.business.ItemBusinessService;
import com.dgs.restfultesting.model.Item;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)             
@WebMvcTest(ItemController.class)  
public class ItemControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;    

    @MockBean
    private ItemBusinessService businessService;

    @Test
    public void retrieveAllItems_basic() throws Exception {

        when(businessService.retrieveAllItems()).thenReturn(
                Arrays.asList(new Item(2, "iPhone", 1000, 10),
                        new Item(3, "Huawei", 500, 17)));

        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/all-items-from-database") 
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON); 

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(request)
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().json("[{id:2, name:iPhone, price:1000}, {id:3, name:Huawei, price:500}]"))  // This will return an array back, so this data should be within an array
                .andReturn();  
    }   

    @Test
    public void createItem() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/items")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content("{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Book\",\"price\":10,\"quantity\":100}")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(request)
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(header().string("location", containsString("/item/")))
                .andReturn();
    }
}
```

There is no problem to test the retrieveAllItems_basic() method, but when I try to run a JUnit test for createItem() method, it doesn't work and I get this: java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<201> but was:<200>

And this is what I receive in the Console:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /items
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json], Accept=[application/json]}
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.dgs.restfultesting.controller.ItemController
           Method = public com.dgs.restfultesting.model.Item com.dgs.restfultesting.controller.ItemController.addItem(com.dgs.restfultesting.model.Item)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
2018-10-07 17:53:51.457  INFO 55300 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@71075444: startup date [Sun Oct 07 17:53:48 EEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
```

**Update -----------------------------**

I try to set the location like this: item/id.

This is the code for the controller:

```
@PostMapping("/items")
public ResponseEntity<Object> addItem(@RequestBody Item item) {
    Item savedItem = businessService.addAnItem(item); 
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance();

    UriComponents uriComponents =
            uriComponentsBuilder.path("/item/{id}").buildAndExpand(savedItem.getId());
    httpHeaders.setLocation(uriComponents.toUri());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(savedItem, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED); 
}
```

This is the code for test:

```
@Test
public void createItem() throws Exception {

    RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .post("/items")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content("{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Book\",\"price\":10,\"quantity\":100}")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(request)
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andExpect(header().string("location", containsString("/item/1")))
            .andReturn();
}
```

When I run the JUnit test for createItem() method I get this error: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Return 201 from your controller:** As your assertion test is expecting `201` by using `created` status but your controller is returning 200(OK).

```
   @PostMapping("/items")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addItem(@RequestBody Item item) {
        Item savedItem = itemBusinessService.addAnItem(item);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedItem, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

**Or modify your test to check status OK(200).** Update your test if you don't want to assert "location".

```
 @Test
 public void createItem() throws Exception {
 RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
        .post("/items")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content("{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Book\",\"price\":10,\"quantity\":100}")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(request)
        .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
}
```

**UPDATE--Allow location header in response**

If you want **"location"** to return from header, then modify your controller and test case below to check location too in header.

STEP 1: In your controller's add item method, add location uri and return.

```
 @PostMapping("/items")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addItem(@RequestBody Item item) {
        Item savedItem = businessService.addAnItem(item);
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance();

        UriComponents uriComponents =
                uriComponentsBuilder.path("/item/").buildAndExpand("/item/");
        httpHeaders.setLocation(uriComponents.toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedItem, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

STEP 2: Now your test will assert `"location"` as you expected.

```
 @Test
    public void createItem() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/items")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content("{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Book\",\"price\":10,\"quantity\":100}")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(request)
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(header().string("location", containsString("/item/")))
                .andReturn();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, but it's not working, I get this error: java.lang.AssertionError: Response header 'location' Expected: a string containing "/item/" but: was null

Comment: @elvis use my updated test from answer to get success result, in your test case i see you are checking location but to order to return location you need to set in your header so to just check item is created or not run test which i posted recently..for location I will recommend you go through with some examples how you can set location in response header then you can add that line in your test too.

Comment: @elvis I have updated answer how you can also return location uri from your response to match..check my answer.

Comment: Thank you kj007, it's working now. I want to ask you something else, what should I do if I modify the code in this way:  UriComponents uriComponents =
                uriComponentsBuilder.path("/item/{id}").buildAndExpand(savedItem.getId());

Comment: that will also work for location item/id..you just need to set location in header..make sure in your test you match with your location you pass

Comment: I try to run it but it fails. Can you have a look at it? I just updated my question. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181474/discussion-between-kj007-and-elvis).

Answer (score 1):

first of all I do not see in your createItem test the mock program part let's say

```
Item item = new Item();
Item newItem = new Item();
when(businessService.addAnItem(item)).thenReturn(newItem);
```

and in your controller I do not see the Location header. Probably a code like below should be better:

```
@PostMapping("/items")
public ResponseEntity<?> addItem(@RequestBody Item item) {
    Item savedItem = itemBusinessService.addAnItem(item);

    return ResponseEntity.created(UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://yourserver/item"));
}
```

I hope that this can help you